# Pandas: filtering rows with & operator does not reduce Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have been reviewing some Posts on stack overflow, but have not found an appropriate answer to my question. I have a dataframe with three columns: player_name, dribbling and pace

```
df2[df2['pace']>50 & (df2['dribbling']>50)].count()
```

shows 16882 entries, which is the whole dataset

```
df2[df2['pace']>50].count()
```

shows 15713 entries and

```
df2[df2['dribbling']>50].count()
```

shows 15089 entries

Why does the `df2[df2['pace']>50 & (df2['dribbling']>50)].count()` **not** reduce the dataset and instead shows all entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
df2[(df2['pace']>50) & (df2['dribbling']>50)].count()
```

Comment: this is obvious enough once it is shown. plus other people having the same problem wouldn't be finding the post anyway. Certainly they wouldn't search the title of this post.

Comment: @YongkangZhao: For me this is not obvious, so an explanation would be very helpful, why all the whole dataset is shown.
A suggestion for a better title would be helpful as well, so users like me would learn to use titles which are helpful for the community.

Comment: the problem is, once the person knows what title to use, they wouldn't be asking, and if the person with the same problem don't realize what the problem is wouldn't be searching for the correct post. This is a problem of understanding of order of operation. and how would someone not knowing it is the problem to ask the right question?

Comment: @David, when you had this problem, you didn't know it was a problem of order of operation and certainly if you knew, you wouldn't have this problem. Similarly, someone else who doesn't realize this wouldn't be searching for THIS post. Since this post is too specific to your problem.

Comment: the title says something about pandas, rows, & operator, filtering; when the problem is just an understanding of order of operation. there is not much to it. and people with the same problem wouldn't be searching for pandas filtering etc.,